# How to distinguish paragraph words from arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have a paragraph like this

> Today I went to a beautiful park, there I saw a white rabbit that was very funny.

Then I have keywords in the array

```
<?php
$keyword = array('beautiful', 'rabbit');
?>
```

I want to make it Bold format, only keywords in the array are not bold. Example :

> **Today I went to a** beautiful **park, there I saw a white** rabbit **that was very funny.**

Comment: Surely you've tried writing more code than that? We aren't going to write it for you, but we'll help you fix your code if youre stuck.

Comment: Please add the code you wrote while trying to find this solution.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: Never once did you even comment under answers given. So you want help and solutions, you need to work for them and gain people's confidence; again IMHO.

Comment: I would take the problem the other way around : write everything in bold except words in your array

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$string = "Today I went to a beautiful park, there I saw a white rabbit that was very funny";
$keyword = array('beautiful', 'rabbit');
$split = explode(' ', $string);
$newString = "<strong>";

foreach($split as $word){
    if(!in_array($word, $keyword)){
        $newString .= " ".$word;
    }else{
        $newString .= " <span style='font-weight:normal;'>".$word."</span>";
    }
}
$newString .= "</strong>";

print($newString);
```